# case insensitive regex matching not working in perl

Tags: regex, perl, csv, case

My regex pattern in perl is correctly matching the case sensitive string, but not the string where the case is different. I am parsing a CSV file where the first row is country names, and the other rows are abbreviations or common other spellings of that country.

Example: column 1 of the CSV is United States, USA, US, America. Column 2 is: Mexico, MX, MEX.

Here is the full code::

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

my $filename = 'countrycodes.csv';
my $line;
my @rowStrings;
my @rows;
my @columns;
```

This is the string I am using to test the code:

```
my $string = "Mex, MEX, USA, usa, US, MX, CAN, Canada";

open(my $fh, '<', $filename) or die "Can't open $filename: $!";

$line = <$fh>;
@rowStrings = split("\r", $line);

#make rows strings into arrays
foreach my $i (0..$#rowStrings){
    $rows[$i] = [split(",",$rowStrings[$i])];
}


my $columnCount = values scalar $rows[0];

print "column count: $columnCount \n";

#create array for each column from CSV
foreach my $column (0..$columnCount){
    foreach my $row (0..$#rows){
        $columns[$column][$row] =  $rows[$row][$column];
        if ($columns[$column][$row]) {
        }
    }

}
```

Here I am going through the arrays of abbreviations / spellings and looking for matches. Searching for any abbreviations from the arrays and replacing them with the header / country name from the CSV file ($head).

```
for my $col (0..$#columns-1){
    my $head = $columns[$col][0];
    for my $ro (1..$#rows){
        if ($columns[$col][$ro]){
            $string =~ s/\s$columns[$col][$ro],/ $head,/i;
            print $string . "\n";
        }
    }

}
```

This is the terminal output as the end result:

```
Mex, Mexico, United States, usa, United States, Mexico, Canada, Canada
```

So as you can see, MEX is matching properly since that is the term it is searching for, but not Mex, even though I am using the /i modifier. What am I doing wrong?

edit: USA is matching, bot not usa.

For reference the regex pattern is `$string =~ s/\s$columns[$col][$ro],/ $head,/i`

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you print out `$columns[$col][$ro]` to see what it things it is trying to match.

Comment: I was printing it out in the beginning. I know that it is matching the exact spellings of the CSV fields, but not when the case is different.

Comment: Probably Mex is not matching because there is no space infront of it, and you are searching specifically for a space there `\s`.

Comment: What about usa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I didn't include the "g" operator, meaning once it found one instance of the Country name alternative, it stopped looking for others.

By changing `$string =~ s/\s$columns[$col][$ro],/ $head,/i` to `$string =~ s/\s$columns[$col][$ro],/ $head,/ig` the matching was correct.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you're doing, but maybe this helps: The \s in your regex tries to match whitespace but won't match absence-of-whitespace. Since your "Mex" is at the beginning of the line, it doesn't have whitespace in front of it. As an experiment, try moving the "Mex" to a different position in the line.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like parsing the CSV is not your problem. (I'd still recommend `Text::CSV` for that.)

Assuming you have your languages and alternatives in an array, and you have an array of these languages-with-alternatives-arrays, you can just compare the inputs. You should probably strip leading and trailing whitespace, and compare case-insensitive, but you don't need a regex for that:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @countries = (   
    ['United States of America', 'US', 'USA', 'US of A', 'United States'],
    ['Mexico', 'MX', 'Mex'], 
);

my @input = ('US ', '  mx   ', ' Mexico', ' us of a');

foreach my $input (@input) {  
    $input =~ s/^\s+//;
    $input =~ s/\s+$//; 
    my $found = 0;
    foreach my $country (@countries) {  
        foreach my $alternative (@$country) {
            if (lc($input) eq lc($alternative)) {  
                print "$input is ${$country}[0]\n";
                $found = 1;
            }
        } 
    }   
    print "did not find $input\n" unless($found);
}
```

Comment: I can't strip everything around the alternatives, because this CSV also includes peoples names which might include those characters.